# "Invalid block tag on line 14: 'empty', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Tags: django

I'm receiving the following error in Django:

"Invalid block tag on line 14: 'empty', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

topic.html Template:

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

    <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

    <p>Entries:</p>
    <ul>
        <% for entry in entries %>
            <li>
                <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
                <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: can you try replacing `{% endblock content %}` with `{% endblock %}`

Comment: You wrote `<% for ... %>` instead of `{% for ... %}` not e the brackets.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs at the `<% for entry in entries %>` template tag, or well what should be a template tag. In Django, template tags are surrounded with `{% … %}` (note the *curly* brackets instead of the *angle* brackets). You thus should rewrite the `for` template tag:

```
{% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
        <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
        <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
    </li>
{% empty %}
    <li>There are no entries for this topic yet.</li>
{% endfor %}
```